querystring is not working to alternates canonical and languages in generateMetadata In Next.js
In Next.js 15, I am trying to use the query string in generateMetadata's alternates.canonical and alternates.languages, but it is not being applied.
How can I ensure that query string is not removed?
The sample code is as follows.
export async function generateMetadata(): Promise<Metadata> {
  const t = await getTranslations('Layout');

  return {
    metadataBase: new URL(process.env.BASE_URL || ''),
    title: t('title'),
    alternates: {
      canonical: '/',
      languages: {
        'x-default': '/',
        en: '/?hl=en_US',
        ko: '/?hl=ko_KR',
      },
    },
  };
}

However, the result is as follows.
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ko" href="/">

